# How To Drop table By hibernate without using HQL or without adding "create-drop"/"create" in hbm2ddl.auto?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

Can anyone tell me how we drop table in hibernate without using any query.

```
session.delete(ABC.class);
```

This is used for clear the data in the table 
but I want to drop the table in hibernate with code like above. Is their any method for this??

please not giving these in your answer

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>

session.createSQLQuery("DROP TABLE abc").executeUpdate();
```

this is done by query or change in hibernate property but i want do this by code or predefined method or with criteria anything else except these.

Answer (score 0):

Without query the DDL operations are not possible, and since they're AUTOCOMMIT, you cannot DROP the table without using query.

Comment: I dont want to write hard coded query for objects  but i want hidden query like criteria and session.delete()...  auto generated query code i need...

Comment: @Aditya The answer is nearly correct. There is no support for DDL operations in Hibernate (without using SQL queries). @Ganesh This has nothing to do with `AUTOCOMMIT`. And you mean _SQL_ query (compared with HQL query).